# Logical Operator: Need some different eyes on this one. Can't figure it out

Tags: php

I have the code below and it results as `true` with the `or` or `||` logical operators. I remove the second condition and it works as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$user = trim(get_user_role());
    if ($user != 'administrator' or $user != 'editor'){

       echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
       echo 'jQuery(".nav > li").eq(2).hide();';
       echo 'jQuery(".nav > li").eq(3).hide();';
       echo '</script>';        
}
```

I even `echo` the user and it is administrator, so I know that part is right.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `&&`

Comment: Yes! Since I was using the `!=` my logic in my head was wrong. Thank you and please make that an answer so that I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, think about it.

```
if($user != 'administrator'... -> False->($user = 'administrator')->Check next condition.
|| $user != 'editor' -> True->($user = 'administrator)->execute.
```

You need to use `&&` here.

Answer (score 3):

You are stating **IF $user IS NOT administrator OR $user IS NOT editor**.  So if `$user` is not administrator it is `true` and if `$user` is not editor it is `true`, either one.

You want to use AND `&&`:

```
if ($user != 'administrator' && $user != 'editor'){
```